# C program Accidental Making Virus..?Why

Tags: c

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main() {
    printf("hello");
    getchar();
}
```

When I compile the above code the created binary is detected by the AVG Antivirus that immediately delete it.

I got the Threat: `Trojan Horse BackDoor.Generic16.BOCF`

Why I am Getting It...?

Comment: Probably a bad false positve

Comment: **False positive** most probably. Some antivirus watch for the creation of executable, try to add the compiler to the safety zone or exclusion in you Antivirus.

Comment: Not relevant to your problem, but the correct definition for `main` is `int main(void) { /* ... */ }`. You're also missing the required `#include <stdio.h>`. More relevant, try making some changes to the program and see if you get the same behavior.

Comment: The problem is that whatever you're creating matches a "signature" that the AV software is looking for.  I had a dickens of a time with some AV software and my Nokia simulator software, since every simulated module produced would be flagged as a "virus".  Had to dump the AV software.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with paulm and NetVipeC as this looks like a false positive. A  false positive is any normal or expected behavior that is identified as anomalous or malicious. [The term false positive is used when antivirus software wrongly classifies an innocuous file as a virus.](http://computersecurity.wikia.com/wiki/False_positive)

You may check for [details](http://www.sans.org/security-resources/idfaq/false_positive.php)

> The major problem that false positives create is that they can easily
>   drown out legitimate IDS alerts. A single rule causing false positives
>   can easily create thousands of alerts in a short period of time. If
>   the assumption is made that an analyst can review one alert every five
>   minutes, the analyst can review around 100 alerts per day. Reviewing
>   one alert every five minutes is too fast for thorough analysis but we
>   can assume that some alerts will not require thorough analysis
>   lowering the average time for analysis. Looking at these numbers it is
>   obvious that only a small number of false positives can drown out
>   legitimate alerts. The alerts for rules that causing repeated false
>   positives are often ignored or disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of this occurring, but perhaps your C runtime library is infected?  This could cause every program produced by static library linking to have the virus.  To test this, recompile and link using "dynamic library linking".

While a false positive is a possibility, I doubt it would be detected in a new program created.  (Unless it is a peculiar AV package.)

Run a full virus scan of all your files to check.  Or switch to an operating system which is less subject to virus attack (Linux, MacOS, etc.) so you don't have to run anti-virus software.

Comment: 1) "Virii" is not the correct plural of "virus." It's just "viruses." 2) "Switch operating systems" is not a reasonable response to this issue.

Comment: @KyleStrand:  1)  I have de-Latinized the phrasing.  2)  Using a naturally virus-resistant operating system is a long term solution.

Comment: What if this is a work machine, and Windows is the required development environment? What if OP needs (or wants) to use some kind of Windows-only software? What if OP is using a Windows box just to learn more about MFC programming? What if OP just likes Windows? The fact is that the real issue here is almost certainly NOT actually a virus, so there's no reason to suggest drastic anti-virus countermeasures--and yes, switching to a different OS is drastic.

Answer (score 0):

I have copied your code exactly and run it successfully in my terminal on my Mac.  I would have to say that your problem is that you are creating an executable that is being picked up by your anti-virus software.